# Is there some interruption by logging with if/else statements in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, logging

Is there some interruption by logging with if/else statements?
I have if/else branching and I need to log both of them. I use two functions for logging:

```
def write_log(var1, var2, var3):
    log_file = 'C:\\path\\file.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='w', format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    log_message = f'{var1} : {var2} in {var3}'
    logging.info(log_message)
```

and almost identical but the log_file variable:

```
def write_another_log(var1, var2, var3):
    log_file = 'C:\\path\\another_file.log'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, filemode='w', format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    log_message = f'{var1} : {var2} in {var3}'
    logging.info(log_message)
```

It is snippet of my function of Class:

```
class Any():
    ...
    @statickmethod
    def needed_function():
        ...
        if one_statement:
            ...
            write_log(var1, var2, var3)

        if another_statement:
            ...
            write_another_log(var1, var2, var3)
```

And in output I don't get two files, all information is in one! I guess, this functions interrupting each other. What I've done to fix it? Hanged everything and still don't know why it isn't works.

Comment: I don't know the case with this 'loggin' library you are using, but with a normal builtin `open` you would use `{filename}.close()`. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`logging.basicConfig` is supposed to be called only once. If it finds that there already is a handler it will just do nothing. Logging to more than one file is not `basic` anymore (as understood by basicConfig).

To do that you would set up your logging something like this:

```
import logging

logger1 = logging.getLogger('logger1')
logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh1 = logging.FileHandler('path/to/file1.log')
fh1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger1.addHandler(fh1)

logger2 = logging.getLogger('logger2')
logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh2 = logging.FileHandler('path/to/file2.log')
fh2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger2.addHandler(fh2)

def write_log(var1, var2, var3):
    log_message = f'{var1} : {var2} in {var3}'
    logger1.info(log_message)

def write_another_log(var1, var2, var3):
    log_message = f'{var1} : {var2} in {var3}'
    logger2.info(log_message)
```